# Linux /include directory enums

Tags: c, linux, enums, kernel

I'm looking at an include file with contains a whole bunch of enums, namely `include/linux/power_supply.h`.

The enums look like this:

```
enum {
    POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS_UNKNOWN = 0,
    POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS_CHARGING,
    POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS_DISCHARGING,
    POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING,
    POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS_FULL,
};
```

I'm porting a driver from a different kernel version, and it won't compile unless I add some `POWER_SUPPLY_xxxx` lines to `power_supply.h`.

Is that the wrong thing to do?  What exactly are these enums and what is their function in the kernel?

-A

Comment: http://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS

Comment: Yes, it is the wrong thing to do.  If the software that's delivered with your system doesn't have the enumeration values you need, the chances are strongly in favour of it not having the functionality that those enumeration values imply.  Don't do it.  Update to a version of the O/S which supports the values you need.  (Or downgrade, I suppose, if they're no longer supported, but you then need to review why you want to use the old software with the outdated functionality.)

Comment: But can somebody explain what the enums actually *do*?

Comment: Does anybody know why in some enums in kernel first members are initialized with 0 ? AFAIK this is guaranteed by C standard or maybe I'm missing some information from very old C standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions in `include/linux/power_supply.h` provide a common set of values for symbols used in `drivers/power`, principly the Charger-Manager described in `Documentation/power/charger-manager.txt`.

The semantics of the values are documented in `Documentation/power/power_supply_class.txt`. Besides providing a common set of values for drivers inside the kernel, `power_supply.h` is also a bridge between the kernel and user-space utilities that control the drivers.

If you change any of these enum values in your kernel, then you will likely have two problems:

1. all other drivers that use these enums could compile correctly but malfunction disasterously at run-time
2. any user-space utility compiled with conflicting values could fail

So, to port the driver, you will need to change the driver code to conform to the `power_supply.h` that your target kernel uses rather than to change `power_supply.h` to fit your driver. That means that you will have to learn the driver code and the semantics of the enum values in both the target and source kernel versions.

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer.  Thanks!